# How do you make a gradient progress bar in JavaFX?

Tags: java, javafx, progress-bar, linear-gradients

I want to achieve this:
https://images.app.goo.gl/rH7o4hssPt1mLeEM9

Currently I've made a progress bar with `-fx-accent: #87CEEB;`

But I want it to be a linear gradient:
`linear-gradient(to right, #87CEEB, #2980b9);`

How can I make it?

Comment: In the link that I've shared the progress bar contains round corners and I don't want that.

Comment: Thanks but I have already read all wikis & I want the color of the progress bar to be gradient.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You just have to use CSS to select the `bar` of the `progress-bar`:

```
.progress-bar .bar {
    -fx-background-color: linear-gradient(to right, #87CEEB, #2980b9);
}
```

Then just add your stylesheet to your scene:

```
scene.getStylesheets().add("Style.css");
```

[image: screenshot]

Comment: Hi Zephyr, actually I'm a web developer (also a c# developer) and I'm new to java but your idea was so good.